# Creating an object inside another object changes 'this'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, crash

I have a C++ class *RendererWidget*, which has an *init()* method. After compiling with Visual Studio 2012 and running it, I get a crash at a pretty strange location:

```
bool RendererWidget::init(Renderer *renderer)
{
  /* ... */
  mRenderer = renderer;
  mViewport = new Viewport();

  return mRenderer->init(mViewport);
}
```

The function is passed a non-nullptr renderer and then creates a *Viewport* object, which has a trivial constructor. The problem is that before *mViewport = new Viewport();*, *this* and *mRenderer* have some defined values and after, *this* changes to something totally different and *mRenderer* changes to 0x0, which causes the crash later. What could be the possible reason?

EDIT as suggested by comments:

Full init():

```
bool RendererWidget::init(Renderer *renderer)
{
    Engine *engine = Engine::instance();

    if (renderer)
    {
        mRenderer = renderer;
        mOwnsRenderer = false;
    }
    else
    {
        mRenderer = engine->createRenderer();
        if (!mRenderer)
            return false;

        mOwnsRenderer = true;
    }

    mViewport = new Viewport();

    // this and mRenderer are already changed here, mViewport is a valid pointer
    mViewport->initFromOther(reinterpret_cast<HWND>(winId()));

    // crash
    return mRenderer->init(mViewport, engine->getMainRenderer());
}
```

Viewport:

```
Viewport::Viewport()
    : mHandle(NULL)
    , mRenderer(nullptr)
    , mAudio(nullptr)
    , mInput(nullptr)
    , mOwnsHandle(true)
{
}

void Viewport::initFromOther(SystemWndHandle hWnd)
{
    mHandle = hWnd;
    mOwnsHandle = false;
}
```

Comment: show us " some defined values"

Comment: Are you compiling in debug mode?
That often happens in Release mode

Comment: By "have some defined values" I mean valid, non-nullptr addresses. I am compiling in Debug mode.

Comment: The problem is in the code you haven't shown us.

Comment: Impossible to answer without more code - sounds like the Viewport constructor or the init method is corrupting things for instance, so we'de need to see what they do

Comment: I added more code to the question.

Comment: Two words: heap corruption.

Comment: Ensure there aren't 2 different versions of the header file laying around and that you have made clean.

Comment: I've run the application through Application Verifier and it shows 0 warnings and 0 errors, yet the effect is still the same. I also found that after the call to *new Viewport()*, both *this* and *renderer* variables are changed to the same value. What's strnager, it's the value returned by *new*. I can't really understand what is happening here.